# Java not inclusive of 100 in 100 Lockers

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

MY desired output is locker 1,4,9,16,36,49,81 **AND** 100.
I'm iterating through trying to find which lockers after a student is sent, and opens every locker. (All are closed by default) and opens every locker. then student number 2 goes to every other locker, and if it is open, close it, and if it is closed, open it. Student three does the same but with every third locker. All the way up to student 100. I know the output should be all the square numbers but I can't get the 100 to show up. What am I missing? I put a <= on both of my iterations and it doesn't work. It throws an IndexOutOfRangeException. What should I do?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class runLocker {
final static int numberOfLockers = 100;
final static int numberOfStudents = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int LockersToCloseBy = 1;
    boolean[] totalLockersArray = new boolean[numberOfLockers];
    for(int i = 0; i < totalLockersArray.length - 1; i++){
        totalLockersArray[i] = false;
    }


    for(int n= 0; n < totalLockersArray.length ; ++n){
        for(int j = 0; j < totalLockersArray.length; j+=LockersToCloseBy){

            if(totalLockersArray[j] == true)
            {
                totalLockersArray[j] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                totalLockersArray[j] = true;
            }   
        }
        LockersToCloseBy++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLockers; i++){
        if(totalLockersArray[i] == true){
            System.out.println("Locker " + i + " is open");
        }
    }


    //Currently outputs 1, 4, 9, 16, 36, 49, and 81...
    //Need it to output 1,4,9,16,36,49,81,100
}
```

}

Comment: Arrays are 0-based, so if you want index 100 to be available, your array must be 101 long, with indexes 0-100.  Also, you don't need to initialize boolean array to false. It's allocated that way.

Comment: The section `if(totalLockersArray[j] == true)
            {
                totalLockersArray[j] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                totalLockersArray[j] = true;
            }` can be replaced with `totalLockersArray[j] = !totalLockersArray[j];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is defined for indices [0,...,99] (100 elements total, exclusive of 100).

In the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLockers; i++){
    if(totalLockersArray[i] == true){
        System.out.println("Locker " + i + " is open");
    }
}
```

100 is not even a candidate.

---

An easy fix could be to set the lockers array at 101 (numberOfLockers=101), so all the loops will be inclusive of 100.

Comment: @cyroxis Assuming you are just skipping the "0" one - you can live with that. It's 101 boolean object, that represent 100 lockers. (and this is exactly what the code is doing by starting from `LockersToCloseBy =1`).